# What's the difference with this 'cross-staff' notation?

Tags: theory, notation

Sometimes I see this cross-staff notation. I'm not even 100% sure cross-staff is the right word for it.

[image: cross staff notation]

The two sets of half notes are joined on both clefs. They are identical but what's the difference between the first and the second? Is there one?

I did first spot this on a Stravinsky score for Apollon musagète (Piano). See highlighted below.

[image: Apollon score]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the same notes written on different staves?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40431/why-are-the-same-notes-written-on-different-staves)

Comment: Cross-staff beaming... I was close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implication in Stravinsky's score is that the notes stemmed together should be played by the same hand. Thus, the right hand could play [DCF][ECE][FCEb].

This is a general convention. Notes are stemmed together when they are intended to be played by one hand. Writing cross-staff like this is typically done to avoid leger lines or to make clear the presence and roles of multiple voices.

The example prior to the Stravinsky shouldn't be written cross-staff, because it can't be played with one hand.